How to fix this roof leak around the chimney
I have a spot in my roof right where it slopes down to the top of the chimney that leaks only with a heavy rain. The main spot where it drips is circled in the below photo. It's not quite abutting the chimney, but off to the side of it a little bit. You can see the whole edge of the wood next to the chimney is blackened - there are more occasional drips along that whole edge.

How should I repair / hire someone to repair this? I had a roofer come, and he looked at it from the ground and said the flashing looked fine, so it was probably windblown rain getting inside the chimney through the mortar joints. However, this is obviously not what's happening from the view inside the attic.
Would a cricket be the thing to do? Or would that just concentrate more water to the circled spot where most of the dripping happens already?

I really need to see the what's on the top before I can  say for sure, but that chimney seems very close to the ridge so a different solution my be better suited.

The cricket is the way to go but I'd sure like to see a better detail on how the water is shed so that it does not seep under the surrounding shingles.

It's a chuckle how often we get asked to diagnose roof leaks from inside. That's not where they are. Why would this photo help?

You don't show the roof, but the thing your roof needs (or the thing already on your roof that needs to be repaired/re-flashed) is indeed a cricket, and it diverts water from accumulating at the upper side of the chimney.
A proper repair here (or installing a cricket newly if missing) will typically require re-roofing from the chimney to the peak in order to address installing all the bits of flashing correctly. So the area where it's leaking in the circle will need to get re-roofed anyway. The cricket moves the water away so it's not pooling and standing, but if there's a leak active it needs to be addressed as part of the solution.
